# Do I need to do more than add env variables in docker-compose file in order to use them across other containers?spin up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I define the URL for my backend service container in my docker-compose.yaml.

```
environment:
  PORT: 80
  VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL: "mm_backend:8080"
```

When the containers spin up, I inspect my frontend container and can verify that the env variable was set correctly as shown below.

[image]

However, when I attempt to use my frontend service to connect to my backend (retrieve data) it tells me that the VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL is undefined in the network tab.

The implementation and usage of this environment variable is such within my vue.js code

```
getOwners(){
    fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL}/owners`, defaultOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((element) => {
          var entry = {
            value: element.id,
            text: `${element.display_name} (${element.name})`
          }
          this.owners.push(entry)
        })
      })
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is the code actually running in a browser?  It will never be able to see Docker environment variables or host names.

Comment: Yes I'm running in browser. So I guess I just have to hard code my urls into my calls then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won’t work because `process.env.someKey` is not available on the browser. In other words, docker-compose won’t help much if you want to pass ***any*** env variable into your front end application. Simplest approach is to define the backendUrl in the code itself at one place and use it to make api calls. If you are not happy doing this, there are already some good answers/solutions available on StackOverflow for this same problem.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing was putting the urls in the code itself and that seemed to work! Thank you.